# implement generic class of child classes

Tags: java, oop, generics

I created an Athlete class.

```
public class Athlete {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final Country sourceCountry;

    public Athlete(int id, String name, Country sourceCountry){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.sourceCountry = sourceCountry;
    }
}
```

then I created the following interfaces and sub classes:

```
public interface IJumper {
    public double jump();
}
```

```
public interface IRunner {
    public double run();
}
```

```
public class Runner extends Athlete implements IRunner {


    public Runner(int id, String name, Country sourceCountryCode) {
        super(id, name, sourceCountryCode);
    }

    @Override
    public double run() {
        return Math.random();
    }
}
```

```
public class Jumper extends Athlete implements IJumper {

    public Jumper(int id, String name, Country sourceCountry) {
        super(id, name, sourceCountry);
    }

    @Override
    public double jump() {
        return Math.random();
    }

}
```

in addition, I created the following RunnerJumper class to create another type of athlete that can both run and jump:

```
public class RunnerJumper extends Athlete implements IRunner, IJumper {


    public RunnerJumper(int id, String name, Country sourceCountry) {
        super(id, name, sourceCountry);
    }

    @Override
    public double jump() {
        return Math.random();
    }

    @Override
    public double run() {
        return Math.random();
    }
}
```

now, I want to create an Team class. the team should be team of runners or jumpers (team of runners can contain Runner & RunnerJumper and team of Jumpers can contain Jumper & RunnerJumper)
so I want the team to be generic..
in addition the team class should have method like "compete" (
something like: forEach Athlete of Team:
run or jump (depends the type of athlete..)
)

how can I achieve this kind of behaviour?

I tried to create it like this:

```
public class Team<C extends Athlete> {}
```

but in this form team of runners cannot contain RunnerJumper..
I also tried to create new interface Competitor:

```
interface Competitor {}
```

and have both IRunner & IJumper extend it..
this seems good at first:

```
public class Team<C extends Competitor> {}
```

but I don't understand how I can Implement the compete functionality in this form...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add your current implementation of your Team class to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do it the way you imagine.

Types - in Java - serve to express guarantees. Things that are 100% certain about a piece of code. If a piece of code gets a `Duck`, there is 100% guarantee that it is also a `Bird` and an `Animal`.

But you cannot express relations like "it's either a `Duck` or a `Bucket`". You would need both to extend the same supertype and make sure that the type is only extended by these two; in general it would require multiple inheritance and sealed types.

And you cannot express relations which mix values with types, like "if the `numberOfLegs == 8`, then the type is `Octopus`". I have no idea how to call the aparatus required for this, but the structural types in Type Script, I think, can express such constraints. I think that duck typing is a prerequisite.

Coming back to Java: if there's a set of objects which can contain `Runner`s or `RunnerJumper`s, the only thing that you can guarantee in the Java's type system is that all the objects are `Runner`s. No generics, inheritance etc. can change that.

You can use one of the multitude of patterns to achieve your business goal:

1. refactor the jumping / running behavior into a separate classes, both implementing `Action` with a single `perform` method. Then create an interface with a single method: `getActions`, called, say, a `Player`. Then, your `Team` can iterate over `Player`s, get actions for each one and call their `perform` method in an inner loop. The implementation of the `getAction` method can even return a static list of lambdas, so that you can access all your player's attributes from inside. This pattern allows you to keep the list of possible actions open (introducing new actions will not require you to recompile or touch your `Team` class).
2. if the list of possible actions is statically known by the `Team`, you can use the `Visitor` pattern - let the Team call the player's `visit` method, and the player can call `Team`'s `playerJumps(Jumper j)` or `playerRuns(Runner r)`.

Or you can use other mechanisms of the language: reflection and casting (this will also make the list of possible actions static).

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is you could create two Team classes, one for the runners and one for the jumpers, like so:

```
public interface Team {
    public void compete();
}

public class TeamRunners implements Team {
    private List<Runner> runners;
    private List<RunnerJumper> runnerJumpers;

    public Team(List<Runner> runners, List<RunnerJumper> runnerJumpers) {
        this.runners = runners;
        this.runnerJumpers = runnerJumpers;
    }

    @Override
    public void compete() {
        for (Runner runner : runners) {
            runner.run();
        }
        for (RunnerJumper runnerJumper : runnerJumpers) {
            runnerJumper.run();
            runnerJumper.jump();
        }
    }
}

public class TeamJumpers implements Team {
    private List<Jumper> jumpers;
    private List<RunnerJumper> runnerJumpers;

    public Team(List<Jumper> jumpers, List<RunnerJumper> runnerJumpers) {
        this.jumpers = jumpers;
        this.runnerJumpers = runnerJumpers;
    }

    @Override
    public void compete() {
        for (Jumper jumper : jumpers) {
            jumper.jump();
        }
        for (RunnerJumper runnerJumper : runnerJumpers) {
            runnerJumper.run();
            runnerJumper.jump();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the idea is to create an exclusive team of runners or jumpers (team of runners can container Runner & RunnerJumper)

Comment: In that case just use two Team classes. I've updated my answer.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier I define the runners to be  List<IRunner> runners ? it will make sure runners are either Runner of RunnerJumper and for `compete` I can iterate the runners and make all of them `run`

Comment: No, you cannot use `List<IRunner>` because IRunner is an interface, so that will not compile.